# How to show specific events from JSON feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsf-2, fullcalendar

I have a JSON feed full of data on the following page :

```
'./PlanningFeed.xhtml'
```

I can show the data on a basic usage fullcalendar and it is working.

The problem is i want to show only events that fulfill a condition.

this is how i get JSON data :

```
eventSources: [
        {
            url: './PlanningFeed.xhtml',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                start: firstdate,
                end: lastdate,
                salle: salle //this is my attempt to get only events that has a specific
                             //"salle" attribute,the field salle is declared and populated
                             //in all event objects.
                             //but this parameter here  it doesn't affect
                             //anything and  my calendar is created with all salle events showed.
                             //which means this doesn't work.
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Also i tried the `eventRender` but no avail:

```
    eventRender: function(event, element) {


        if (event.salle === salle) {
            console.log('added', event.salle);

        } else if (event.salle !== salle) {
            console.log('deleted', event.salle);
            $(placeholder).fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);

        }
    }
```

I don't want to delete the data from the JSON feed i may use it later. i wish if i could query the JSON feed to show only events that i want(for example : event.salle='XYZ').

Do not hesitate asking for further info.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
[{"title":"uiyuiyutyiyuity\nANGIO SCANNER RENALE.","start":"2014-12-01T07:30:00","end":"2014-12-01T07:45:00","salle":"SCANNER1","backgroundColor":"#B6E8FF","patState":4,"rapportWrittenState":0,"patientFullName":"uiyuiyutyiyuity","studyDureeMinute":15,"payStateImage":"non-cote","bannerColor":"#98d1ec","borderColor":"#98d1ec","id":"1"},
 {"title":"hjghjghjghj\n2 CHEVILLE F","start":"2014-12-01T07:15:00","end":"2014-12-01T07:35:00","salle":"RADIO 1","backgroundColor":"#CDDFED","patState":1,"rapportWrittenState":0,"patientFullName":"hjghjghjghj","studyDureeMinute":20,"payStateImage":"non-cote","bannerColor":"#a0c2dc","borderColor":"#a0c2dc","id":"2"},
 {"title":"yiyuiyuiyui\nANGIO SCANNER ABDOMINALE.","start":"2014-12-01T06:55:00","end":"2014-12-01T07:15:00","salle":"SCANNER1","backgroundColor":"#F0F0F0","patState":7,"rapportWrittenState":0,"patientFullName":"yiyuiyuiyui","studyDureeMinute":20,"payStateImage":"non-cote","bannerColor":"#C8C8C8","borderColor":"#C8C8C8","id":"3"},
{"title":"tuutyuj\nANGIO SCANNER CEREBRAL.","start":"2014-12-01T06:25:00","end":"2014-12-01T06:45:00","salle":"SCANNER1","backgroundColor":"#E8F5BB","patState":5,"rapportWrittenState":0,"patientFullName":"tuutyuj","studyDureeMinute":20,"payStateImage":"non-cote","bannerColor":"#cede97","borderColor":"#cede97","id":"4"},
{"title":"dfgdfgdfgdfg\nANGIO SCANNER CERVICAL.","start":"2014-12-01T06:00:00","end":"2014-12-01T06:20:00","salle":"SCANNER1","backgroundColor":"#FFC592","patState":3,"rapportWrittenState":0,"patientFullName":"dfgdfgdfgdfg","studyDureeMinute":20,"payStateImage":"c_valider","bannerColor":"#e8a66c","borderColor":"#e8a66c","id":"5"}]
```

Comment: Can you show sample code of your json return?

Comment: instead of asking full calendar to trigger the ajax, can't you just send the request, get the data, filter the data, save it in an array and give that as the input for full calendar?

Comment: becuz i will need to create 5 fullcalendra instances in the same page and everyone of them needs to show specific events from the same JSON feed, how can i explicitly tell everyone of them which data to fetch/show.

Comment: I'm not sure that `$(placeholder).fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);` works. Also I use this syntax for events:
`events: 
{
   url: 'path/events.php',
}`
Now I'm testing for your case.

Comment: I can display the events i have no problem with that, my question is how can i show only specific fulfilling a condition events from a JSON feed which is full of events (in other terms i have a JSON feed of all 5 rooms in one day,and i want every calendar to show the events of a single room, how may achieve that ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by calling fullcalendar from server side with ajax oncomplete as i use JSF.

1. Load specific data from  database.
2. Use GSON to convert it into a JSON String.
3. Load the arrays of events to the calendar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very good in full calendar, but I found solution for your problem

After deleting event, you must rerender all events:

```
$(placeholder).fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
 setTimeout(function(){
 $(placeholder).fullCalendar("rerenderEvents");
},1);
```

I use timeout for sure. It's testing for fullcalendar-2.2.3 fresh download.

EDIT:
be sure for your variables and if conditions.

Comment: it worked now, but i see all events and then the ones that i don't to see disappear.

Comment: but isn't there any better solution like fetch only the dat athat i need ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var eventStore;// store pre filtered events here so we can get at them later
...
events: function(start,end,callback) {
    $.ajax('http://www.myendpoint.com/getevents.php', {start:start,end:end}, function(data) {
        var events = JSON.parse(data);
        eventStore = events;
        var newEventList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
            if(events.salle == true){
                newEventList.push(events[i]);
            }
        }
        callback(newEventList);
    });
}
```

It probably makes the most sense to have your webservice filter the data and return what you need, but you can filter the events prior to display using a custom function as above.